# Parsley v2.0.0-rc2 binding on non form element from javascript

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

How to bind parsley.js v2.0.0-rc2 to non form element (e.g div) and change default errors container from js?
In my case I need errors to be below validated element parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you want to bind inputs grouped inside a div, simply add `data-parsley-validate` on the div. It would be considered as a Form with its fields inside.

2) Regarding errors messages, you could leverage [this config function](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html#section-14) like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.ParsleyConfig = {
        errorsContainer: function (parsleyField) {
            return parsleyField.$element.parent().parent();
        }
    };
</script>
```

Placed before calling parsley.js would tell ParsleyUI to **append** error messages to **each** field's grandparent.

Comment: But what if i am including parsley in Layout which is used by multiple pages and i need different containers for different pages?
I know that i can include parsley on every specific page and do this but is there any other way?

Comment: You could locally do this trick, passing the ParsleyConfig above object to $('#element').parsley(ParsleyConfig) directly (and be sure to remove data-parsley-validate to your form)

Comment: But parsley is bound on <div>, not form, and if I remove data-parsley-validate I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'validate' "

Comment: Mhh I see. You would have to add then window.Parsley.autoBind = false;

Comment: So i need to set window.Parsley.autoBind = false; and leave data-parsley-validate attr in <div> ?

Comment: Yes. You are in a quite special case here. You need data-parsley-validate attr to force div binding, but must avoid parsley auto bind on this attr on startup. Using autoBind=false; will prevent that and let you bind it manually with proper options! Phew!